# Error with react-map:"Did you wrap <GoogleMap> component with withGoogleMap() HOC?"

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am starting a web app using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). I just begun coding it and I am getting this error:

```
Did you wrap <GoogleMap> component with withGoogleMap() HOC?
▶ 21 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | registerServiceWorker();
   9 | 
  10 | 
View compiled
▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Here's the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <GoogleMap/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Obviously there's nothing wrong with the code and might be a version problem. Here's my dependencies:

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",
"react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: show your GoogleMap component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY></script>
```

in your html file and you should be fine (change they key of course).

Or wrap the script via withScript() like so:

```
import withScriptjs from 'react-google-maps/lib/async/withScriptjs';


const myMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) => 
(<GoogleMap />)));
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the right answer. I just copied the code from the first part of the tutorial thinking it would work.

Comment: It throws props error when using TypeScript. For older projects it's not a valid JSX object `Property 'myMap' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'` also can we do this inline somehow you think?

Comment: I have tried these options but it doesn't solve my problem. I'm still getting the error, please refer to the full console error log below               _'Warning: Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree. The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version. Please update the following components: withGoogleMap(Component)'_

Answer (score 3):

You can use these:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

import {
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    GoogleMap,
    Marker
} from "react-google-maps";


class Map extends Component{

    static defaultProps = {
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSySEDDFRGFQSw2OjzDEE1-tDsN7vw&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



    CMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props =>
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={8}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </GoogleMap>
      ));



    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <this.CMap
                    googleMapURL={this.props.googleMapURL}
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `700px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    center= {{ lat: 25.03, lng: 121.6 }} 
                >
                    <Marker
                        position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
                    />
                </this.CMap>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}


export default Map;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have noticed, this question is quite old and already has an accepted answer. You can find more recent, unanswered questions using the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag.

Comment: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'